# Why does this pattern not match?

Tags: python, regex

Using this pattern:

`(?<=\(\\\\).*(?=\))`

and this subject string: `'(\\Drafts) "/" "&g0l6P3ux-"'`

I was expecting to match `Drafts`

However, it is not working. Can someone explain why?

I am using re module in Python,the following is what I did:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile("(?<=\(\\\\).*?(?=\\))")
>>> pattern.pattern
'(?<=\\(\\\\).*?(?=\\))'
>>> two
'(\\Drafts) "/" "&g0l6P3ux-"'
>>> match = pattern.search(two)
>>> match
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1096e45e0>
>>> match.groups()
()
>>> match.group(0)
'Drafts'
>>>
```

my question is why `groups` get nothing but `group` get the right answer?

Comment: can you provide the actual code and error you're getting? You have provided so little information

Comment: are you sure, you have all these double `\\` decoded the right way? in your regex you look for two backslashes, Drafts have only one.

Comment: Did you use [Python’s raw string notation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)? Put an `r` before to reduce [escape level](http://www.regular-expressions.info/python.html): `r"(?<=\(\\\\).*(?=\))"` else might need to write 4 backslashes to match a single literal backslash. Also would make the [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` [lazy](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html): `.*?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`match.groups()` is empty because your pattern does not define any capturing groups. `match.group(0)` is the complete match, while `match.group(1)` would be the first capturing group if there was one.

To improve readability you should express regex patterns as raw strings. Yours can be written as

```
r"(?<=\(\\).*?(?=\))"
```

To break it down, there is a lookbehind for literal `(\`, then `.*?` and finally a lookahead for literal `)`.